# If you randomly pick $m$ numbers from $1$ to $n$, what is the probability that at least $m-1$ numbers that can be arranged in consecutive order?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Hi I have this question and I do not quite understand why the solution is much lower than my intuition:

If you randomly pick $m$ numbers from $1$ to $n$, what is the probability that you have at least $m-1$ numbers that can be arranged in consecutive order?
Edit:
I.e. m= 8 numbers from 1 to 10 could be $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ or $3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ A sequence that doesn't skip a number. I hope this explains it better.
These numbers can be picked in any order, as long as they can be arranged in such a way as above.
/end of edit.

I thought that the probability should be at least that of picking exactly $m$ numbers that can be arranged in order.
I thought this would be $\frac{m \choose m-1}{n \choose m}$.
For example this with $ n = 10$ and $m = 9 $ gives me $\frac{9}{10}$ however the correct solution is $\frac{4}{10}$.

I am likely making a thinking mistake but I can't find it.
Thank you for your help!

PS:
I was also thinking with at least I would have to take $1 - $ the probability that it can't happen.
Well that's when there is a gap, so that's not picking $2$ numbers for the example aboth? But this gives me something way to low again.

Comment: Please clarify with an example what is meant with "can be arranged in order" ? Can't we arrange every finite set of numbers in order ?

Comment: Oh I am sorry. Like in a consecutive sequence without missing one number. I. e. 8 from 1 to 10 could be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: And the numbers must already appear in this order ? So, $5,4,1,3,2,6,7,8,10,9$ would qualify as a $3$-example because $678$ appears, correct so ?

Comment: @Peter no, this is why I mean arranged. So in your example $1,3,2$ would also count as I could I arrange it in order I am sorry. This is literally the wording from my problem.

Comment: In case $n=10$ and $m=9$ isn't it so that such order is only possible if one of 10,9,1, 2 is not picked?

Comment: @drhab yes, I think so. But in general this doesn't give me a formula

Comment: @oliver So we search the longest chain of consecutive integers appearing somewhere in the set ? So, my above example would qualify as a $10$-example, right ?

Comment: @Peter Thanks. I am not sure this is correct, but I am obviously not solving this problem correctly.

Comment: While I don't have the solution yet, thanks to chatting with you @Peter I think I see the mistake in my attempt! That's something at least haha. thank you

Comment: In fact, the missing number must be $1,2,9$ or $10$ leaving a chain of $8$ or $9$ numbers. Hence $4$ choices out of $10$ do the job.

Comment: @Peter this is what I tried to do with $1- \frac{n \choose 2}{n \choose m}$ but this gives me an impossibility. PS I really appreciate the help. I have pretty much given up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1,2,\dots,n-m+2$ let $E_{i}$ denote the event that the numbers
$i,i+1,\dots,i+m-2$ are among the $m$ picked numbers.

Then to be found is: $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-m+2}E_{i}\right)$$

Applying the principle of inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-m+2}E_{i}\right)=\left(n-m+2\right)P\left(E_{1}\right)-\left(n-m+1\right)P\left(E_{1}E_{2}\right)=$$$$\left(n-m+2\right)P\left(E_{1}\right)-\left(n-m+1\right)P\left(E_{1}E_{2}\right)$$

Here $P\left(E_{1}\right)=\frac{\binom{m-1}{m-1}\binom{n-m+1}{1}}{\binom{n}{m}}=\frac{n-m+1}{\binom{n}{m}}$
and $P\left(E_{1}E_{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}}$ so we arrive
at:

$$\cdots=\binom{n}{m}^{-1}\left[\left(n-m+2\right)\left(n-m+1\right)-\left(n-m+1\right)\right]=$$$$\binom{n}{m}^{-1}\left(n-m+1\right)^{2}$$

Sanity check $n=10$ and $m=9$ is passed.

Comment: thank you so much for this. I tried this with 2 values just now and it works totally fine. I have to study it a bit more to completely understand, such a nice derivation.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Hi, I hope I don't pester you too much. I have been able to understand your inclusion exclusion principle and the following derivation that leads to the final formula. 
I am however struggling to really get how you arrived at $P(E_1)$ and $P(E_1E_2)$. I wrote out all the possibilities and see it's correct. I just feel I am missing the "understanding".

Comment: Let me try to explain with example $m=3$ and $n=5$. The event $E_1$ occurs iff we pick 1,2,3 or 1,2,4 or 1,2,5. So $n-m+1=5-3+1=3$ favourable outcomes on a total of $\binom53=10$ possible and equiprobable outomes. The events $E_1$ and $E_2$ occur both iff we pick 1,2,3. So 1 favourable outcome on a total of again $\binom53=10$ possible and equiprobable outcomes.

Comment: thank you very much. This example made things much clearer again. I feel quite silly since this is the second time I am solving this and I couldn't even remember how to arrive at the solution after your clear derivation above. It finally clicked! Thank you again for your patience.